Issue with DataGrid Selection in WPF Application
A WPF application has been developed using .NET 5, which includes a DataGrid and a button. The following is the code for the button's click event.
The issue encountered is that the index and selectedRow values of the DataGrid are only correctly stored during the first click.
Subsequent clicks on another row do not update the values of index and selectedRow. Extensive searches for a solution have not yielded results. Guidance is appreciated.
private void ModifyProductSellPrices(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{   
    var selectedRow = (ProductSize)dgrdMain.SelectedValue;     

    int index = dgrdMain.SelectedIndex;         

    AppWindows.ModifyProductSellPrices modify = new ModifyProductSellPrices(selectedRow);     

    modify.ShowDialog(); 
}  

I expect the current values of index and selectedRow to be retrieved with each button click. However, this only happens on the first click, and on subsequent clicks, the values of these two variables do not change.

Share more of your code , how is the function is  being called ? directly from xaml and this is the code behind?

.NET 5 is no longer supported. If one chooses to use >= .NET 5, then one has to upgrade the .NET version at least every two years to ensure one is using a supported version. See .NET Lifecycle.

In this window, the DataGrid columns are created in the code-behind, and the click event is also set in the code-behind. However, in another window where the DataGrid and its columns are created in the XAML and the click event is set, the same issue occurs.And I am forced to use .NET 5 for compatibility.

There's insufficient code and markup to answer this question. It's also a little strange thing you're doing. If you set selection mode to single you can just bind selected item and work with that.

I set the SelectionMode  to single, but the problem was not resolved.

Have you tried using one of the events fired by the DataGrid, rather than the button, to trigger the update?
